# Upload an AWS S3 file into Dropbox via PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using PHP to get my object from AWS S3 and then turn around and upload it into Dropbox. I can successfully get the object from AWS, but when I try and upload the file into Dropbox I just an empty Json reponse with no error or anything. I know that my $dbToken (Dropbox token) is working right because I can use the same key to get my folder structure and list files.

When I try and upload a file it just goes blank. I think it has to do with the AWS presigned URL. Do I need to make a Curl request to get the contents of that url ($secureUrl in my case). Not sure how to write that and how to get this file into Dropbox. Thanks for your help.

```
        # ============================================
        # Connect to AWS and get the Object
        # This works fine...
        # ============================================
        $s3 = new S3Client([
            'credentials'=>[
                'key'=>xxxxxxx,
                'secret'=>xxxxxxx,
            ],
            'region'=>'us-west-2',
            'version'=>'2006-03-01',
        ]);
        $cmd = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', [
            'Bucket' => xxxxxxx,
            'Key'    => xxxxxxx,
        ]);
        $request = $s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+60 seconds');
        $secureUrl = (string) $request->getUri(); // get signed uri...
        # echo $secureUrl; // if I echo this on the page, I can see the url, copy it and paste it into the browser and all works well...

        # ============================================
        # Connect To DropBox and Upload File...
        # This is returning nothing in my output...
        # ============================================
        $dbToken = 'xxxxxxx';
        $headers = [
            "Authorization: Bearer ". $dbToken,
            'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path": "'.$secureUrl.'", "mode": "add", "autorename": true, "mute":false }',
            "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
        ];
        $url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload';
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $path = $secureUrl;
        $fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $data = json_decode(trim($result), TRUE);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data); // the json response is empty...
        echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Can you print the full HTTP response for the Dropbox API call, including status code and response headers? Also, note that the response isn't guaranteed to be JSON (you can check the `Content-Type` to see) but that being the case you may want to try just printing out `$result` before you try to `json_decode` it.

Comment: I this, Error in call to API function "files/upload": Missing or empty HTTP "Content-Type" header.  Expecting one of "application/octet-stream", "text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack". But as you see in my script I am including the headers: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"

Comment: So, I've hard coded the AWS file into the headers and this is the error that I now get: Error in call to API function "files/upload": HTTP header "Dropbox-API-Arg": path: 'https://aws.file.url/OjRwJYK0yLv2lzaeEVROyvSID8vSipB4APFjGAlh/OjRwJYK0yLv2lzaeEVROyvSID8vSipB4APFjGAlh.png' did not match pattern '(/(.|[\r\n])*)|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)|(id:.*)' ... is it even possible to upload a remote file into drop box or does it have to be a local file?

Comment: The `path` parameter for the [/2/files/upload](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload) call should be desired path inside the Dropbox account, e.g., `"/some folder/file.ext"`. It also requires the file content be provided directly in the request body. If you only have a remote URL, you should use [/2/files/save_url](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-save_url) instead.